# What is the relation between the rank of $A$ and the rank of the cofactor matrix of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Let $A \in M_5(\mathbb{R})$. If $A = (a_{ij})$, let $A_{ij}$ denote
>   the cofactor of entry $a_{ij}$, $1 \leq i, j \leq 5$. Let $\hat{A}$
>   denote the matrix whose $(ij)$th entry is $A_{ij}$, $1 \leq i, j \leq
> 5$.
>
> 1. What is the rank of $\hat{A}$ when the rank of $A$ is 5?
> 2. What is the rank of $\hat{A}$ when the rank of $A$ is 3?

It is a standard result that $A\hat{A}^T = (\det A) I$. This follows pretty much immediately from the expansion formula of determinants along rows.

If rank $A = 5$, then $\dim \text{null } A = 0$ by the rank-nullity theorem. So, $\det A \neq 0$ and $\hat{A}^T$ is invertible. As rank $B = \text{ rank } B^T$ for any matrix $B$, $\hat{A}$ is invertible. Thus, rank $\hat{A} = 5$.

As for the second question, I find myself stumped. In this case, as $\det A = 0$,
$$ A\hat{A}^T = 0$$
We can conclude that the range of $\hat{A}^T$ is entirely contained in the nullspace of $A$, which has dimension 2. So, rank $\hat{A}$ = rank $\hat{A}^T$ is at most $2$, but I can't figure out how to say definitely what the answer is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix of co-factors is identically zero when $A$ has rank $3$.

The thing is that if rank of $A$ is three, then all $5\times 5$ and all $4\times 4$ sub-matrices must have determinant zero. Otherwise the rank would be larger than $3$. In particular, all co-factors, determinants of $4\times4$ sub-matrices are zero.

Comment: I didn't quite understand why all $4 \times 4$ submatrices will have determinant 0.

Comment: @Anu If one such submatrix has non-zero determinant, then look at the columns passing through it. Those vectors are linearly independent (do Gauss elimination on the submatrix to make it triangular with non-zero elements in the diagonal, which you can do since its determinant is non-zero). If $4$ columns were linearly independent, then the rank would be $4$ (at least).

Comment: That makes sense, the corresponding columns in the $5 \times 5$ matrix will be linearly independent, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Anu Now, do the case of $rank(A)=4$.

Comment: I was just about to ask! Does this guarantee a nonzero cofactor?

Comment: @Anu The thing is that $4\times 4$ submatrices coincide with the matrices from which the co-factors are computed. Then some cofactor is non-zero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73218/discussion-between-anu-and-jfkeys).